# Style first row after dropdown list is open

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.CategoriesList, "categoria")
```

and I want to specify a style for the first row, but only when the dropdownlist is opened, and  keep the style of the label over it:

I tried the

```
.as-ads-filter-field select:first-child
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

but the label "categoria" is bold even when the list is closed, and I only want to be bold, when the list is opened to distinguish from the list values.

EDIT:

Html output:

```
<select id="CategoryId" name="CategoryId">
   <option value="">categoria</option>
   <option value="1">Carros</option>
   <option value="2">Motos</option>
   <option value="5">Comerciais</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rVYeq/
Thanks

Comment: If you want to get help from CSS community, consider posting the HTML output as well.

Comment: Can you post a working example with the HTML and CSS on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have posted the HTML output and fiddle working example

Comment: I don't think you can do that using html+css only. Take a look at the select.mousedown and select.click events for identifying when the select is open/closed. Be aware that it might be tricky to implement a solution that works cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT change the option style except `background-color` and `color`.

See below reason, it's from [MSDN: option element | option object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Except for background-color and color, style settings applied through
>   the style object for the option element are ignored.

You can see the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/lin/rVYeq/1/